# Reference interface from outside project

Tags: c#, interface, projects-and-solutions

Imagine I have a visual studio solution containing two projects. In this scenario, Project 1 is aware of Project 2, but Project 2 is NOT aware of Project 1.

**Project 1**

```
using Project2;

namespace Project1
{
   public class ClassA : IMyInterface {}

   public class Main {

       public void MainMethod()
       {
           ARandomClass aRandomClass = new ARandomClass();
           IMyInterface classA = new ClassA();
           aRandomClass.MyItem = classA;
           aRandomClass.MyMethod();
       }

   }
}
```

**Project 2**

```
namespace Project2
{
   public interface IMyInterface { }

   public class ARandomClass {
      public IMyInterface MyItem { get; set; }

      public void MyMethod() {
         Type type = MyItem.GetType(); // what happens here?
      }
   }
}
```

My question really is what would happen if we try to get the type of an object inside a project that has no reference/knowledge of that type?

Would it return the interface? Can it?
Is it somehow able to reference the type?
Would it return "object"?
Or would it do something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would return the actual type `ClassA`.

All the type information is available and inspectable via reflection. You simply can't directly reference the type at compile-time.

Project 2 *could* still call members on `ClassA`, it would just be difficult/cumbersome because you would be limited to using reflection or `dynamic`.

```
public void MyMethod() {
    Type type = MyItem.GetType(); //gets a `System.Type` representing `ClassA'
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);//outputs "Project1.ClassA"
}
```

Just do demonstrate what you can or cannot do, say `ClassA` was defined as:

```
public class ClassA : IMyInterface 
{
    public string MyField = "Hello world!";
}
```

You would not be able to do this:

```
public void MyMethod() {
    Console.WriteLine(MyItem.MyField); //compiler error
}
```

You *could* do this because Project2 can access information from Project1 *at runtime*:

```
public void MyMethod() {
    //lookup the field via reflection
    Type type = MyItem.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(type.GetField("MyField").GetValue(MyItem));

    //simpler way than above using dynamic, but still at runtime
    dynamic dynamicItem = MyItem;
    Console.WriteLine(MyItem.MyField);
}
```

But you *couldn't* do this because Project2 has no knowledge of Project1 *at compile time*:

```
public void MyMethod() {
    //cast to type ClassA
    ClassA classAMyItem = (ClassA)MyItem; //compile error
    Console.WriteLine(classAMyItem.MyField); //compile error
}
```

This is basically one of the tenants of polymorphism though. Your `MyMethod` shouldn't know, and shouldn't care *what* class `MyItem` is beyond it being an `IMyInterface`. It should generally only care about accessing the properties, methods, and events as defined on `IMyInterface`. If it *does* care about it being an instance of `ClassA`, then you might want to reconsider your design or usage.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. I've was always under the impression that the methods in one project are run from within that project and that they only had access to the types that are available at compile time. The scenario I described occurred to me randomly and kept bugging me enough to post this question!

Answer (score 2):

You will get the type as Project1.ClassA

Answer (score 1):

The code you see in Project 2 is still going to be run from Project 1, that's where your call is and therefore will be able to give you the correct information about what the type that Interface is.

My guess would be the output will be something like Project1.ClassA with whatever you have before it. But to be sure just run that code and see what output you get

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MyMethod() {
         Type type = MyItem.GetType(); // what happens here?
      }
```

type variable will point to your `AClass`. You can change your code to looks like this:

```
   public IMyInterface MyMethod()
        {
            Type type = MyItem.GetType(); // what happens here?
            IMyInterface value = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return value;
        }
```

Now you can use instance of your class using interface without much of reflection (Activator is using reflection inside to create an instance).